# In Chrome Extension, need help passing a variable to the current tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying a Chrome Extension to open urls from a list one by one in the same tab. When one URL is opened, I want the corresponding serial number from the list to be available as a variable in the opened page console.

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "URL Opener",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Open URLs from a list and execute code snippets.",
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content_script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["execute_code.js"]
}
```

popup.js

```
let urls = [
  {
    "serial": 1,
    "url": "https://www.example.com",
    "codeSnippet": `console.log("Hello, World! It's an example.");`,
    "uniqueString": "example123"
  },
  {
    "serial": 2,
    "url": "https://www.google.com",
    "codeSnippet": `alert('This is Google! "Search the world"');`,
    "uniqueString": "google456"
  },
  // Add more URLs with their respective fields as needed
];

let currentIndex = 0;

function openNextURL() {
  if (currentIndex >= urls.length) {
    alert("All URLs from the list have been opened.");
    return;
  }

  let urlObj = urls[currentIndex];

  // Get the current tab
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
    if (tabs.length > 0) {
      let currentTabId = tabs[0].id;

      // Update the current tab with the new URL
      chrome.tabs.update(currentTabId, { url: urlObj.url }, () => {
        currentIndex++;
        updatePopupUI(urlObj);

        // Send message to the content script to execute the code snippet
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
          currentTabId,
          { type: "EXECUTE_CODE", tabId: currentTabId, serial: urlObj.serial },
          (response) => {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
              console.error("Failed to execute code in content script:", chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else if (response && response.success) {
              console.log(`URL Serial on page: ${response.urlSerial}`);
            } else {
              console.log("Failed to set URL Serial on page.");
            }
          }
        );
      });
    }
  });
}

function updatePopupUI(urlObj) {
  if (currentIndex < urls.length) {
    document.getElementById("current-url").innerText = `Opening URL ${urlObj.serial} of ${urls.length}:`;
    document.getElementById("url-details").innerHTML = `
      <strong>URL:</strong> ${urlObj.url}<br>
      <strong>Code Snippet:</strong><br>
      <pre>${escapeHTML(urlObj.codeSnippet)}</pre><br>
      <strong>Unique String:</strong> ${urlObj.uniqueString}
    `;
    document.getElementById("open-button").innerText = "Open Next URL";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("current-url").innerText = "All URLs have been opened!";
    document.getElementById("url-details").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("open-button").disabled = true;
  }
}

function escapeHTML(str) {
  return str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
}

document.getElementById("open-button").addEventListener("click", openNextURL);
updatePopupUI(urls[currentIndex]);
```

content_script.js

// content_script.js

```
// This content script will be injected into all web pages

// The execute_code.js script will be dynamically injected into the page
const executeCodeScript = document.createElement("script");
executeCodeScript.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("execute_code.js");
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(executeCodeScript);
executeCodeScript.onload = function () {
  executeCodeScript.remove();
};

// Listen for messages from the popup
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (message.type === "EXECUTE_CODE") {
    // Execute the code snippet
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: message.tabId },
      files: ["execute_code.js"],
    });

    // Set URL serial variable in the page's context and send response back to popup
    let serial = message.serial;
    chrome.scripting.executeScript(
      {
        target: { tabId: message.tabId },
        func: (serial) => {
          window.urlSerial = serial;
        },
        args: [serial],
      },
      () => {
        // Send a response back to the popup after setting the URL serial variable
        sendResponse({ success: true, urlSerial: serial });
      }
    );

    // Return true to indicate that the response will be sent asynchronously
    return true;
  }
});
```

The urls open one by one when I click on the popup. However, never got the variable urlSerial in the console.

Answer (score 0):

1. Content scripts can't use most of `chrome` API such as chrome.scripting.
2. The `scripting` API is only available in ManifestV3.
3. `activeTab` only works for the site in the tab at the moment of invoking (clicking) the extension, it won't work after you navigated the tab to a different site, so you'll need to add the sites explicitly in `host_permissions`.

**The solution** is to run the content script code directly in the context of the page by specifying `MAIN` world in executeScript instead of separate files and messaging.

1. Remove `content_scripts`, `web_accessible_resources`, content_script.js, execute_code.js
2. Rename `browser_action` to `action` and update these fields in manifest.json:

```json
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": ["scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["https://www.example.com/", "https://www.google.com/"],
  "action": {
```

3. Update popup.js:

```js
async function openNextURL() {
  const [{id: tabId}] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const urlObj = urls[currentIndex];
  await chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: urlObj.url});
  try {
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      world: 'MAIN',
      target: {tabId},
      args: [urlObj.serial],
      func: s => { window.urlSerial = s; },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    document.body.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I'm still struggling to accommodate this in my borrowed code. Appreciate if you/someone can post complete code for all required files.

Comment: This is the only js file. The other files should be removed as listed in step 1 of my answer.